# Delete row from database using Servlet

Tags: java, mysql, database, servlets

I had a problem in my servlet regarding deleting record from my database. Please look over my servlet code and please do correct me.

ViewBooksServlet.java servlet displays the records in database along with a "Delete" hyperLink in every row. But problem is whenever i try to press delete button.. the elseif loop runs and it show deleted from  DeleteBooksServlet.java servlet but the data is not deleted from the database.. Please guide me how can i delete the record from databse either from id or from book_name.

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    Connection con=null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/books_online","root","");
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("Select * from books");
        out.println("<html><table width='50' border='1'>");
        out.println("<tr><td>Id</td><td>Name</td><td>Author</td><td>Price</td></tr>");
        
        while(rs.next())
        {
            out.println("<tr><td>"+rs.getInt(1)+"</td><td>"+rs.getString(2)+"</td><td>"+rs.getString(3)+"</td><td>"+rs.getString(4)+"</td><td><a href='deletebook'>Delete</a></td></tr>");
        }
        out.write("</table></html>");
        
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

DeleteBooksServlet.java

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{       
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();   
    Connection con=null;
    try {
        
        String id=request.getParameter("id");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/books_online","root","root");
        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("delete from books where id=?");
        ps.setString(1, id);
        int i=ps.executeUpdate();
        if(i!=0)
        {
            out.println("Deleting rows");
        }
        else if(i==0)
        {
            out.print("deleted");
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Use a debugger. See what you get in the `id` variable. I suspect you get nothing at all, as you are not passing the parameter to the servlet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably because of the following lines:

```
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("delete from books where id=?");
ps.setString(1, id);
```

From the code of `ViewBooksServlet`, it looks like `id` is an `int` and not a `String`. I would use `setInt` method instead of `setString` to delete by id, e.g.:

```
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("delete from books where id=?");
ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(id));
```